# Why there is only one modulus for a Klein bottle?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, mathematics

In Polchinski Page 207, there is a claim that only one modulus for a Klein bottle, I tried to understand this claim, Here's what I have tried:
As I understand, modulus means the geometries that are not equivalent under Diff*Weyl group, the standard Klein bottle is defined by identify
$$
(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)\sim(-\sigma^1,\sigma^2+2\pi t)\sim(\sigma^1+2\pi,\sigma^2)
$$
I may define:
$$
(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)\sim(-\sigma^1+a,\sigma^2+2\pi t)\sim(\sigma^1+2\pi,\sigma^2),a\in\mathbb [-\pi,\pi)
$$
here appears another modulus $\it{a}$, I want to know why this is not a modulus.\

Here's another way to think, which also lead to a wrong answer: consider small deformation of the metric that is orthogonal to all variations, I first take $g_{ab}$ to be flat $\delta_{ab}$ and vary it to $\delta_{ab}+\delta g_{ab}$:
$$\delta g_{ab}(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)=\delta g_{ab}(\sigma^1+2\pi,\sigma^2)$$
$$\delta g_{ab}(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)=\delta g_{ab}(-\sigma^1,\sigma^2+2\pi t)$$
$$(P^T\delta g,\delta \sigma)=0$$
$$\delta g_{ab} g^{ab}=0$$
I didn't tried to solve the whole equation, but I've tried to get two solutions:
$$
\delta g_{ab}=(0,1;1,0)\\
\delta g_{ab}=(1,0;0,-1)
$$
the second one corresponds to modulus t (after a coordinate transformation), but maybe there is something wrong with the first one.

Comment: $a$ can be set to zero by relabelling coordinates $\sigma^1 \to \sigma^1 - \frac{a}{2}$ so it is not a modulus.

Comment: @Prahar oh yeah, you are right, I forgot this translation. And please tell me if this translation can be seen as a new CKV?

Comment: Translation in $\sigma^1$ is not a symmetry as there is a special ${\mathbb Z}_2$-invariant point ($\sigma^1 = \frac{a}{2}$ in your notation). The only CKV in this case is translations in $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Prahar Yeah, I think I got the idea, if I do the translation, the new coordinate has different 'a' in the boundary condition, then it is not homeomorphic to itself.